# How is the output (a list) of the "Eigenvalues" function ordered?

Tags: eigenvalues, order

The documentation of the function **Eigenvalues** says that the Eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute values. But what is if the absolute values are the same. For example when two Eigenvalues are additive inverse.

```
A3 = {{2, 2}, {3, -2}};
Eigenvalues[A3]
(* {-Sqrt[10], Sqrt[10]} *)

A4 = {{-3, 4}, {-5, -2}};
Eigenvalues[A4]
(* {1/2 (-5 + I Sqrt[79]), 1/2 (-5 - I Sqrt[79])} *)
```

What is the exact order of the eigenvalues?

Comment: You say that their absolute value is the same, then say it's not the order mentioned - why not ?

Comment: Oh, you are right! 
I mean: what is the expected order? I need this order to connect this values to the corresponding Eigenvectors.

Comment: Okay, I can solve this problem by using the function Eigensystem.
However, it would still be interesting to know how the Eigenvalues function works

Comment: Actually that Details note applies only to approximate numeric matrices. For other cases, they will be in whatever order `Roots` gives in solving the characteristic polynomial equation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since `Eigenvalues` is a kernel function, we cannot spelunk into its source code. However, we can play with randomly generated matrices, and observe the results.

```
Block[{n = 8, m, d},
 m = RandomInteger[1, {2 n, 2 n}];
 d = DiagonalMatrix@RandomSample@Flatten[{{1}, {-1}} . {RandomInteger[100, n]}];

 Eigenvalues[m . d . Inverse[m]]
 ]

(* {-99, 99, -91, 91, -82, 82, -61, 61, -56, 56, -40, 40, -18, 18, -3, 3} *)
```

Repeating the procedure above, we can see that the eigenvalues are indeed always sorted as:
$$\{-\lambda_1, \lambda_1, -\lambda_2, \lambda_2, \dots \}, \quad \lambda_1 \geq \lambda_2 \geq \cdots \geq 0 $$

However, when using inexact numbers, the numerical error can result in two eigenvalues, which are supposed to come in pair, yet their magnitude will differ slightly. This will seemingly break the ordering we expect.

```
Block[{n = 4, m, d},
 m = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {2 n, 2 n}];
 d = DiagonalMatrix@RandomSample@Flatten[{{1}, {-1}} . {RandomReal[{0, 1}, n]}];
 Eigenvalues[m . d . Inverse[m]]
 ]

(* {0.884406, -0.884406, 0.763995, -0.763995, -0.485294, 0.485294, -0.0857119, 0.0857119} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

Too long for a comment. Let us make a math experiment to this end.

```
m = {{Reduce[x^5 - 1 == 0, x][[1, 2]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, 
{0,ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 - 1 == 0, x][[2, 2]]], 0, 0, 0}, 
{0, 0,ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 - 1 == 0, x][[3, 2]]], 0, 0}, 
{0, 0, 0,ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 - 1 == 0, x][[4, 2]]], 0}, 
{0, 0, 0, 0, ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 - 1 == 0, x][[5, 2]]]}}
```

> `{{1, 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, -(1/4) - Sqrt[5]/4 - I Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, -(1/4) + Sqrt[5]/4 + I Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 0,  0}, {0, 0, 0, -(1/4) + Sqrt[5]/4 - I Sqrt[5/8 + Sqrt[5]/8], 0}, {0,  0, 0, 0, -(1/4) - Sqrt[5]/4 + I Sqrt[5/8 - Sqrt[5]/8]}}`

```
Eigenvalues[m]
```

> `{1, 1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[2 (5 - Sqrt[5])]),  1/4 (-1 - Sqrt[5] - I Sqrt[2 (5 - Sqrt[5])]),  1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5] + I Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])]),  1/4 (-1 + Sqrt[5] - I Sqrt[2 (5 + Sqrt[5])])}`

As we see, these are ordered clockwise starting from `1`.One more case:

```
k = {{Reduce[x^5 + 1 == 0, x][[1, 2]], 0, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 
ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 + 1 == 0, x][[2, 2]]], 0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 
ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 + 1 == 0, x][[3, 2]]], 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 
ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 + 1 == 0, x][[4, 2]]], 0}, {0, 0, 0, 0, 
ComplexExpand[Reduce[x^5 + 1 == 0, x][[5, 2]]]}};

Eigenvalues[k] // N
```

> `{-1., 0.809017 + 0.587785 I,  0.809017 - 0.587785 I, -0.309017 + 0.951057 I, -0.309017 -  0.951057 I}`

I don't see any certain order here.